# Ping from subinterface

Tags: 14.04, ping

I have interface eth0:0

```
auto eth0:0 iface eth0:0 inet static
        address 192.168.2.96
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.2.1
```

and I try this:

```
ping -I eth0:0 8.8.8.8
```

and I get this

```
ping: SO_BINDTODEVICE: Invalid argument
```

If I try to ping from eth0 everything is OK. I am using ubuntu 14.04. How to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

The eth0:0 seems to be an alias interface for eth0. That's why not able to interface from alias name. Kindly assign an individual(either virtual or physical ) interface.